# Extracting fundamental amplitude/phase from only half a period of a pseudo-sinusoïd

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform

Before you read my problem, I've summed up my experiments in a [notebook available here.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/180uMAgl_dO_xOOpX-Zv4p2k3GmKXa8C1)

So, I have a few noisy samples (~50) of a pseudo sinusoidal signal for which I use a traditional discret Fourier transform in order to extract the amplitude and phase of the fundamental (real signal is much noisier).

```
fft[1]=5.0, 60.0°
```

[image]
Now my problem is that i sometime have only half the data available, ie only half a peridod of that sinusoid.
But I know I almost exactly have sample of half that period, and I know the signal is almost a sinusoid.

How can I proceed to extract the fundamental characteristics anyway?

I've noticed that zero-padding the missing half and doubling the amplitude works quite well.

```
fft[1]=2.5, 59.1°
```

[image]

But in my case the sinusoid is not DC-centered on zero, and in that case zero-padding doesn't work.

```
fft[1]=10.6, -82.5°
```

[image]

I would need to pad with the DC of my signal, which is unknown. I've noticed that if you have half a period, the average of first and last samples should give the DC, but this won't be reliable with noisy data.

```
fft[1]=2.5, 59.1°
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for your insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the frequency (and it seems that you do), simply construct a basis set of vectors from

1) DC (all ones)

2) Half a Sine wave

3) Half a Cosine wave

These form an orthogonal basis just like a DFT.  In fact you can think of it as a "one half bin and DC bin" specialized DFT.

Discard the DC reading (unless you care) and use the Sine and Cosine coefficients just like a regular DFT bin from which you can calculate magnitude (which gives you amplitude with a multiplication) and the phase (using atan2).

This will give you a best fit answer.  No window function and no zero padding.

---

Small correction (sorry):  The basis is not orthogonal.  You will need to solve a system of equations.

$$ x[n] = A \cos( \omega n ) + B \sin( \omega n ) + C $$

As a vector equation:

$$ \vec x = A \vec c + B \vec s + C \vec u $$

With some dot products, you get the system of equations with $A,B,C$ as the unknowns to be solved for.

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec c = A \vec c\cdot \vec c  + B \vec s\cdot \vec c  + C \vec u \cdot \vec c  $$

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec s = A \vec c\cdot \vec s  + B \vec s\cdot \vec s  + C \vec u \cdot \vec s  $$

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec u = A \vec c\cdot \vec u  + B \vec s\cdot \vec u  + C \vec u \cdot \vec u  $$

Note:

$$ \vec c \cdot \vec u = \vec u \cdot \vec c = 0 $$

$$ \vec c \cdot \vec s = \vec s \cdot \vec c = 0 $$

$$ \vec u \cdot \vec u = N $$

Where $N$ is your sample count.  Thus the equations simplify to:

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec c = A \vec c\cdot \vec c  $$

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec s = B \vec s\cdot \vec s  + C \vec u \cdot \vec s  $$

$$ \vec x \cdot \vec u = B \vec s\cdot \vec u  + C N $$

---

In order to get the best results with noisy data it is best to build the basis vectors over the full range of data you have and then solve the full set of equations.  A little more work, but likely worth it.

---

Okay, for the OP and maybe Ben.  Here is a sample program for the best fit of a partial cycle.  In this case 0.6 of a cycle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#==========================================================
def main():

#---- Set Parameters, Base Frequency and Phase

        f_s = 50.0
        p   = 60.0 * np.pi / 180.0

#---- Set Domain Time and Angle for partial cycle

        t = np.arange( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 / f_s )
        a = 2.0 * np.pi * t * 0.6

#---- Construct the Signal

        x = 10.0 * np.cos(        a + p ) \
          +  0.2 * np.sin(  2.0 * a )     \
          +  0.2 * np.sin( 10.0 * a )

#---- Build Basis Vectors

        c = np.cos( a )
        s = np.sin( a )
        u = np.ones( a.shape )

#---- Do Basis Dot Products

        cc = c.dot( c )
        ss = s.dot( s )
        uu = u.dot( u )
        cs = c.dot( s )
        cu = c.dot( u )
        su = s.dot( u )

        print cs, ss, uu, cs, cu, su

#---- Do Signal Dot Products

        xc = x.dot( c )
        xs = x.dot( s )
        xu = x.dot( u )

        print xc, xs, xu

#---- Build Coefficient Matrix

        M = np.array( [[ cc, cs, cu ],  \
                       [ cs, ss, su ],  \
                       [ cu, su, uu ] ] )

        print M                       

#---- Build Values Matrix

        V = np.array( [xc, xs, xu] )

        print V

#---- Solve for the best fit "Bin Value"                       

        R = np.linalg.solve( M, V )

        print R

#---- Calculate the Best Fit parameters

        A = R[0]
        B = R[1]
        C = R[2]

        D   = np.sqrt( A*A + B*B )
        phi = np.arctan2( -B, A )

        print D, phi, p

#---- Construct the Best Fit signal

        y = D * np.cos( a + phi ) + C

#---- Show the Results

        plt.plot( t, x )
        plt.plot( t, y )

        plt.show()


#==========================================================
main()
```

And these are the results:

[image]

These are the values:

```
Underlying target:

    10.0
p =  1.0471975512

Found best fit:

D   = 10.1939671316 
phi =  1.04122684844
```

---

Changing the parameters a little bit for a smaller portion (0.3) of the cycle and moving it up by 20.

```
        x = 10.0 * np.cos(        a + p ) \
          +  0.2 * np.sin(  2.0 * a )     \
          +  2.0 * np.sin( 10.0 * a )     \
          + 20.0
```

Results:

[image]

Notice this isn't as accurate because of the smaller cycle portion.

```
D   = 10.4409622651
phi =  0.943824736628
```

However, if the signal is a pure tone:

```
        x = 10.0 * np.cos( a + p ) + 20.0
```

The results are still exact on less than a third of the cycle:

```
D   = 10.0 
phi =  1.0471975512
```

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I will try it

Comment: @Ben Very good.  I kind of blew the simplicity of the answer.  See my update.

Comment: Ced, are you sure that $\vec u \cdot \vec s = 0$?  i agree with you that $ \vec s \cdot \vec c = 0$ and $ \vec u \cdot \vec c = 0$.  but i don't think that $ \vec u \cdot \vec s = 0$ for the half period that the phase is between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Did you add this comment before my followup?  What you say is correct.

Comment: How do you justify the decomposition in $ A \cos( \omega n ) + B \sin( \omega n ) + C $, by using $ D \cos( \omega n + p) = D \cos( \omega n) \cos(p) - D \sin( \omega n) \sin(p) $ ? In that case $ A = D \cos(p), B = -D\sin(p) $

Comment: @JulienM It is justified by being the least squares best fit to the signal of the basis vectors.  The vectors are chosen to be your ideal signal plus an offset.  Yes, that is how you solve for the phase and amplitude.

$$ D = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} $$

$$ p = \operatorname{atan2}(-B,A) $$

Comment: With noiseless data, this should get you an exact solution.  This is how a DFT works, except for two things.  First, In a DFT the basis vectors all have an integer number of cycles in the frame so thay are all mutually orthogonal, making the coefficient matrix diagonal and thus trivial to invert (implicit inversion).  Second, the conventional definition of the DFT uses $-i\sin(\omega n)$ where $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{N}k$.  That is why there is a negative in front of the $B$ and the "bin value" in this case is $A-iB$ instead of $A+iB$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the python version of your solution. I had started implementing it but replaced it with your code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_QKS8iXGkCDI8gv2foOTJuDxOsTKJd4n#scrollTo=dOevAJBHmbs5 I will try on my slighly noisier data

Comment: @JulienM  You're welcome.  Your link is behind a password so I couldn't see it.  This approach should work quite well with noise, particularly if it is "well-behaved", e.i.  Gaussian white noise (GWN).  You can choose any number of basis vectors as long as they are linearly independent.  The more linearly independent they are (orthogonal to each other) the more noise resistant your solution will be.  The deeper DSP lesson here is an insight into how the DFT actually works and what it means, I hope everybody reading this catches that.

Comment: @JulienM I'm able to see it now.  In your last print statement, I think you intended to print "phi", not "p" as you have it now.  The results look pretty good.  It nailed the offset, didn't it?

Comment: A note about your reformatting:  When you have huge program listings (particularly if they are monochromatic), it greatly improves readability when the comment stream is more separate from the code stream when you are holding the page down key looking for a particular something.  By reducing the vertical spacing and killing the indentation, you reduce the comprehensibility, IMO. The tradeoff of more code on the screen usually doesn't gain you much.  Since that is your code, and this is a "religious" matter, I'll shut up about it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this algorithm is helpful to you.

1. You could denoise the half period of samples you have available and then calculate the DC on this sinusoid using this denoised signal.
2. Next you zero pad and interpolate the original half period signal (noisy version) and now pad the DC you calculated is step 1

Comment: Can you tell me how to compute the DC in step 1, considering I have half a sinusoid with unknown phase?

Comment: So first step is to low pass filter the noisy signal, you could use a moving average filter or leaky integrator, any low pass filter that is good enough for the nosie you have, then integrate over half the period the modulus of the sinuoid/your filtered signal (since you do not know the phase), I assume you know the frequency, this result should always be constant over any phase, and the right hand side of this integral will depend on the amplitude (which would give you the DC, you can now calculate RMS) and frqeuency

Comment: Sorry to be slow. Yes I do know the frequency. Do you mean that after filtering, I should sum abs(signal) over 0-Pi? It's not clear how I can retrieve the DC. Integral of a sinusoid over half a period is not constant. And I can't take the modulus of the signal if I don't know the DC

Comment: I mean after denoising take the absolute value of the signal and integrate this function over half a period

Comment: My signal is strictly positive (values are pixel coordinates), if I sum its values over half a period, I won't obtain something constant over any phase. For instance ⌒ or ◡ won't sum up to the same value

Comment: You have to integrate, not sum as I mentioned above, these are different operations

Comment: How shall I integrate my discrete signal? And how is that different from summation?

Comment: Look over the "int" function in Matlab, just Google integration in MATLAB, integration is are under the curve, summation is just the sum of the points.

Comment: For a positive and discrete signal, integration == summation, or there's something I'm missing?!

Comment: Ofcourse in MATLAB, everything wil "look to be"l be discrete, even when u define time t = 0:0.1:1. We can still define numerical integration. But your problem statement is a sinuoisd, which is corrupted by noise, which in real world would be continuous. Just have a look at your first plot, the plot named "signal" is actually defined over discrete points in MATLAB, but is modelling a continuous sinuoisd, just use " Int" function over the the absolute value of filtered sequence with proper limits. Integrating a sinusoid ovrler half period is equal to $\frac{A}{\pif_o}$, A is amplitude of sinusoi

Comment: $\f_o$ is the frequency of sinuoisd in Hertz

Comment: I don't want to waste your time, but I still don't understand. I'm not using Matab and my signal is not continuous, I have only 25 samples points as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an instantaneous frequency estimation question. Have you ever tried Hilbert Transform? Or Hilbert Huang transform (For noisy signal )?

In fact, according to statistic signal processing, the CRLB of 
single tone  frequency estimation problems hast been discussed and bounded via observing time (dominant), SNR, and fps. During the development of MLE, DTFT hast been taken into account so the zero padding (sampling more from DTFT) has its limits.

So, some no classical method (maybe parameter based ) should be tried.

Here I listed some method I know:

1. [AR/ARMA model](https://poweidsplearningpath.blogspot.com/2019/04/ch11-better-frequency-resolution.html?m=1)
2. [Hilbert transform](https://pyhht.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/hilbert_view_nonlinearity.html)

Comment: I quickly tried pyhht.emd.EMD() but it fails with an error since, with only half a period, it cannot find any IMF. Regarding AR/ARMA, i'm not sure it will help since I'm more interested in the magnitude/phase of my sinusoid than it's frequency. (I assume the frequency is known)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- The input is 1/2 period, frequency is known
- The waveform is exactly a sinusoid
- The signal is sufficiently over-sampled
- The amplitude is unknown
- The phase is unknown

I guess you could do time-domain cross-correlation, something like this:

```
fs = 30;
T = 1;
t = 0:(1/fs):(T-1/fs);
a = 2.4;
phi = +1.1;
f = 0.5;
x = a*sin(2*pi*f*t+phi);
x = x + 0.1*randn(size(x));

t_template = 0:(1/fs):(T/((2/3)*f)-1/fs);
x_template = sin(2*pi*f*t_template);
[c, lags] = xcorr(x, x_template);
[mv, mvi] = max(c);
mvi = lags(mvi);
a_hat = sum(x.^2) / mv
phi_hat = -(pi/2)*(mvi/fs)/f
```

Comment: I believe it won't work with my waveform which is a waveform+DC, DC contribution to xcorr will bias the max

Comment: Are you adding DC independently, or are you talking about the DC offset that stems from truncating a sinoid?

Comment: Independant (unknown) DC